# PyV8 Segmentation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pyv8

I have following piece of code.

```
import PyV8

class Global(PyV8.JSClass):
     def __init__(self):
        pass

out = []
with PyV8.JSContext(Global()) as ctxt:
    ctxt.enter()
    op = ctxt.eval("function as(){return {'error':['ssda','sadsadds'], 'warning':[],'score':1};} as();")
    print(op['error'])
```

I am getting `Segmentation fault` while running above code with `python 3.4.3` while it is working fine with `python2.6`.
Here is the snapshot.

[image]

```
(pyv8Pyvhon34)[root@ip- pyToJs]# python --version
Python 3.4.3
(pyv8Pyvhon34)[root@ip- pyToJs]# python pyv8Testing.py
ssda,sadsadds
Segmentation fault
(pyv8Pyvhon34)[root@ip- pyToJs]# deactivate
[root@ip- pyToJs]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@ip- pyToJs]# python pyv8Testing.py
ssda,sadsadds
```

I am using version 1.0.dev0 of PyV8

Comment: enable core dumps on your system (if not enabled already) and use gdb to view the stacktrace

Comment: hi, i am also getting this "Segmentation fault", have you resolved it?